# how can i get multiple quality(360p,480p, 720p) selection for any html5 video with uploading single video file

Tags: html, video, youtube, video-player

I need a video player with quality selector like Youtube or VK. I wanna upload only 1 video, not multiple videos for each quality. And the player must be convert to quality for clicking quality options.

Is it possible ?

And how Youtube or VK can do something like that ?

Comment: upload at highest quality (obviously you can't magically create more "quality") and then use something like `ffmpeg` to transcode to the different bitrates you want. For future-proofing you may want to look at creating `MPEG-DASH` manifest and assets

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a video to YouTube, it creates lower quality versions of the same video. It ends up with several versions of the same video at different resolutions. So although you only upload once, it stores several versions on disk, which are created at the time of upload.

[Here](https://www.quora.com/Does-YouTube-store-multiple-resolution-copies-of-a-video-or-transcode-on-the-fly) is an ex-YouTube employee talking about this.

If I were you, I'd see if I could just use YouTube for what you're planning.

Comment: Hello Richard, its a big video project so i cant use Youtube or another opensource video site. Looks like we need a software for creating lower quality videos from single video.

Comment: Yep, that's what you'll have to do. Transcode on upload. At least you know you're doing the same thing YouTube does!